# is it possible to autolayout the width of the UISlider

Tags: objective-c, uislider, pure-layout

I am using `PureLayout` to put a `UISlider` between 2 buttons as below:

```
[self.slider autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeading  toEdge:ALEdgeTrailing   ofView:self.leftButton withOffset:10.0f];
[self.slider autoPinEdge:ALEdgeTrailing toEdge:ALEdgeLeading    ofView:self.rightButton withOffset:10.0f];
[self.slider autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisHorizontal];
```

Is it possible that the `UISlider` automatically sets its width between the `leftButton` and the `rightButton` ?

Comment: are you want UISlider Width diynamic According to left and right button ?

Comment: yes. The slider starts from the left button to the right button. With the above code, it works well, but the NSLayoutConstraint is broken.

Comment: why you are not set the constrains manually? it is very easy to define in your case.

Comment: Provide all your constraints setup, the constraints may broken because of left or right button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To autolayout the width of UISlider you should provide the width of left and right button. Also, you have to pin them to the superview edges. Then you're able to pin LEFT edge of slider to RIGHT edge of leftButton, and RIGHT edge of slider to LEFT edge of rightButton.

Example code :

```
cell.contentView.addSubview(leftButton)
cell.contentView.addSubview(slider)
cell.contentView.addSubview(rightButton)

rightButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
rightButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Right)
rightButton.autoSetDimension(.Width, toSize: 100)
rightButton.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 50)

leftButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
leftButton.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Left)
leftButton.autoSetDimension(.Width, toSize: 100)
leftButton.autoSetDimension(.Height, toSize: 50)

slider.autoPinEdge(.Leading, toEdge: .Trailing, ofView: leftButton, withOffset : 5)
slider.autoPinEdge(.Trailing, toEdge: .Leading, ofView: rightButton, withOffset : -5)
slider.autoPinEdgeToSuperviewEdge(.Top)
```

[image]